# Is it possible to set background color of hostingview in coreplot?

Tags: ios, core-plot

i need to set background color of hosting view in core plot to clear color.can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Core Plot hosting view is a subclass of `UIView`. It should default to a clear `backgroundColor`. See the [UIView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/backgroundColor).

You can also set a fill on the graph using your image instead of placing it in the background.

```
graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageWithCGImage:myCGImage]];
```

This is just one example. `CPTImage` also has several other initialization methods.

Comment: Thanks For The Reply. I tried it but , its not working for me. i want to keep an image on the view and then add hosting view on it with clear color. so that my graph can be seemed like its plotted on that image.

Comment: with this method to fill Graph with image has no effect on it.even i tried to fill PlotAareaFrame with image.and it gives a black screen.

Comment: Set the `fill` of the graph, plot area frame, and/or plot area to `nil` to make them transparent. The hosting view should be transparent by default.

Comment: Thanks. I got the solution. i filled the PlotAreaFrame with image and its done what i wanted. Thanks For your help.